# Is the process() function of cakePHP supposed to run more than once?

Tags: cakephp, middleware

Using cakePHP middleware, I noticed that the function process() might be running more than once. Evident from log files. I'm not sure if this could have side effects yet. Example below:

```
class FooMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    use LogTrait;


    public function process(
        ServerRequestInterface $request,
        RequestHandlerInterface $handler
    ): ResponseInterface
    {

        $this->log('Repeat?');  
        return $handler->handle($request);  
    }
}
```

On my logs I get identical timestamps.

```
2020-04-13 23:15:21 Error: Repeat?
2020-04-13 23:15:21 Error: Repeat?
```

Is this expected?

EDIT

```
$middlewareQueue
        // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
        // and make an error page/response
        ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))

        // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
        ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
            'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime'),
        ]))

        // Add routing middleware.
        // If you have a large number of routes connected, turning on routes
        // caching in production could improve performance. For that when
        // creating the middleware instance specify the cache config name by
        // using it's second constructor argument:
        // `new RoutingMiddleware($this, '_cake_routes_')`
        ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this))
        ->add($csrf)
        ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this))
        ->add(new FooMiddleware())
        ->add(new AuthorizationMiddleware($this));

        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            // Disable authz for debugkit
            $middlewareQueue->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
                if ($req->getParam('plugin') === 'DebugKit') {
                    $req->getAttribute('authorization')->skipAuthorization();
                }
                return $next($req, $res);
            });
        }

    return $middlewareQueue;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not supposed to run more than once, unless it's included in the middleware queue more than once.

Do some additional debugging to figure what is happening, for example log the stacktrace:

```php
$this->log(\Cake\Error\Debugger::trace());
```

and log in `webroot/index.php` too:

```php
\Cake\Log\Log::write(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::ERROR, 'index.php hit');
```

That should reveal whether the middleware is invoked multiple times (and from where), or if it's actually multiple requests.

Comment: The webroot/index.php is getting "index.php hit" twice as well. My middleware queue calls my middleware once. Edited question.

Comment: @back2back So you probably have multiple requests. Check your browsers script and network console to figure why that might be. Maybe there's a redirect, maybe you're doing a cross origin request causing a preflight request to be issued, maybe a reload is required because of missing encoding information (Firefox likes to do that), maybe it's maybelline.

Comment: On my log stacktrace, I can see the middleware queue being called but I suspect these 2 calls Cake\Http\Runner::run() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 58
Cake\Http\Server::run() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 90